# Expected number of virus cells

Tags: probability, algorithms

I've found this question in a past programming assignment from a course I'm currently reading.

Its statement looks like this :

> A recent lab accident resulted in the creation of an extremely dangerous virus that replicates so rapidly it's hard to predict exactly how many cells it will contain after a given period of time. However, a lab technician made the following observations about its growth per millisecond:
>
> $\bullet$ The probability of the number of virus cells growing by a factor of $a$ is $0.5$
>
> $\bullet$ The probability of the number of virus cells growing by a factor of $b$ is $0.5$
>
> Given a, b, and knowing that initially there is only a single cell of virus, calculate the expected number of virus cells after $t$ milliseconds. As this number can be very large, print your answer modulo $(10^9 + 7)$ .

As I have no prior training in probability or combinatorics, this problem doesn't make much sense to me . I've done some searching about expected values in the context of probability, but I can't see how to model the data I'm given. Perhaps there's something very obvious I'm missing, but I'm not able to see it at the moment.

How would you solve this?

Comment: The absence of actual values for $a$ and $b$ makes it impossible to carry out some definite calculation, even modulo $(10^9+7)$.  Also the confusion about a how many cells a virus "will contain" suggests a rather amateurish "programming assignment" construction.

Comment: This is even more confusing, are you saying there's no chance for a closed form expression or that this can't even be done algorithmically in the given conditions?

Comment: I'm saying it makes a difference what the values of $a$ and $b$ are.  That information is omitted from your problem statement.

Comment: Well. this is always the case with algorithmic challenges in order to avoid test-driven code writing, so there must be a way to solve this without prior knowledge of the actual values.

Comment: As a general approach you could use a probability transition matrix.  It isn't clear whether "growing by a factor of $a$" is supposed to mean a transition from $x$ cells to $ax$ cells, or instead to $(a+1)x$ cells.  Perhaps the material you are reviewing has a worked example that makes the meaning plain.

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting problem, but I think I have a solution:

- At time $t=0$ there is definitely just one virus cell, nothing to argue about here.
- At time $t=1$ there are $a$ cells with probability 1/2, and $b$ cells with prob. 1/2. The average is then $(a+b)/2$.
- At time $t=2$ there are $aa$ cells with prob. 1/4, $bb$ cells with prob. 1/4 and $ab=ba$ cells with prob. $1/4+1/4=1/2$. Average: (aa+bb+2ab)/4
- Et cetera...

What's the pattern? To generate all possibilities of the next generation of cells, we take the possible strings of a's and b's from the previous gen in two copies, concatenate an $a$ to one set of copies and a $b$ to the others. We multiply the probability of each old string by 1/2 to keep the expectation in check, and add things up.

But we don't have to generate actual strings!! (This is good, it avoids exponential blow-up). All we have to do, is take the average of the previous generation, divide by 2, and multiply by $(a+b)$, and we're good to go.

So...we just compute $(\frac{a+b}{2})^{t} \mod (10^9+7)$, and this is efficiently done (like $O(\log t)$ time) using repeated squaring. Just be careful of integer overflow, and you're done :)

(Feel free to ask for more details if necessary, I'm writing this in the middle of the night where I live…the above may not be as clearly written as I would like it to be)

Comment: This is a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of times the "virus cell" population grew by factor $a$ in the $t$ milliseconds. 
Thus the population of 1, after $X$ growths of factor $a$ and $t-X$ growths of factor $b$ will be: $$\begin{align}N_t =&~ a^X b^{t-X} \\ = &~ b^t (a/b)^{X} \end{align}$$

Now, as $X$ is is the count of 'successes' in a series of $t$ independent Bernoulli trials with success rate $0.5$, it will have a Binomial Distribution.   $X\sim\mathcal {Bin}(t, 0.5)$

Now can you find this?  $~\mathsf E(N_t)$

---

**Hint:** A useful research topic is "moment generating functions".

> If $X\sim \mathcal{Bin}(n,p)$ then $\mathsf E(\mathsf e^{sX}) = (1-p+p\mathsf e^{s})^n$.   This is the **moment generating function** for a Binomial Distribution.